# How to determine if ecommerse site is magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have an eCommerce link reference given by my colleague. I want to know if the site is using magento as a platform or built by scratch for some reason. I don't have access to the source code of the website? How can I can determine if the base platform is magento or not?

Comment: First off, this isn't a programming question so flagging to close. Even then, I can't think of a non-dodgy reason for trying to work out whether something is magento or not...

Comment: You can use wappalyzer chrome plugin.

Comment: Suck in any of a number of Magento stock skin and js files and look at them. Magento leaks this information all over the place and has all sorts of Magento copyright notices in plain view.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a Chrome plugin such as BuiltWith https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith-technology-prof/dapjbgnjinbpoindlpdmhochffioedbn?hl=en

I can't guarantee that it will detect Magento but it's worth a try.